# Zero Inflated Poisson Distribution: Fail to estimate the parameter with error code 100

Tags: r, distribution

Following is a kind of data set I am working on it:

```
data <- c(0, 1, 0, 11, 2, 0, 3, 0, 0, 2, 1, 3, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 3, 
0, 0, 0, 8, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 2, 7, 0, 0, 0, 5, 2, 3, 6, 1, 1, 
5, 2, 9, 0, 0, 1, 21, 16, 2, 9, 6, 25, 2, 1, 12, 16, 14, 15, 
15, 6, 1, 12, 12, 13, 5, 5, 6, 4, 7, 11, 8, 4, 5, 8, 3, 8, 4, 
7, 4, 7, 2, 5, 6, 4, 5, 1, 0, 8, 5, 6, 8, 9, 8, 9, 7, 7, 9, 8, 
9, 4, 4, 7, 13, 9, 13, 12, 10, 9, 8, 7, 11, 5, 5, 0, 1, 33, 4, 
22, 19, 22, 9, 5, 4, 17, 7, 7, 4, 5, 3, 0, 0, 9, 3, 0, 0, 36, 
40, 5, 4, 0, 11, 0, 7, 5, 25, 39, 26, 4, 20, 12, 4, 17, 3, 22, 
12, 14, 8, 9, 11, 7, 11, 10, 9, 16, 6, 24, 8, 5, 6, 14, 3, 9, 
4, 1, 20, 0, 1, 7, 9, 0, 12, 2, 29, 56, 16, 8, 28, 0, 19, 25, 
35, 87, 56, 66, 60, 58, 14, 10, 12, 13, 13, 34, 26, 18, 13, 22, 
13, 12, 15, 41, 11, 11, 11, 5, 6, 7, 8, 8, 17, 16, 12, 21, 38, 
34, 10, 77, 41, 7, 12, 1, 16, 20, 8, 5, 2, 20, 7, 16, 12, 6, 
10, 31, 12)
```

I have used the `fitdistrplus`  package to fit distribution using maximum likelihood.
Similarly, `gamlss` package defines the pdf, CDF of zero Inflated Poisson distribution.

```r
library(fitdistrplus)   
library(gamlss)
```

Here is the mean and standard deviation of the data set.

```r
mu=mean(data)
sigma=sd(data)
```

The mean of the data set is 10.75 and the standard deviation is 13.050. I have tried to fit the zero-inflated Poisson distribution using fitdist function as below.

```r
fit_zip = fitdist(data, 'ZIP', start = list(mu = mu, sigma = sigma))
```

Once the stated function is compiled  then the compiler throws the following error

```
Error in fitdist(data, "ZIP", start = list(mu = mu, sigma = sigma)) : 
  the function mle failed to estimate the parameters, 
                with the error code 100
```

It is obvious that there is a problem in the initialization of the starting value of mu and sigma. I am not sure on what basis starting values are initialized.
any help is appreciated.

Comment: 1) Study `help("zip")`. The parameter `sigma` isn't the standard deviation. 2) Recall that for the Poisson distribution E(x) == var(x). Then compare `mean(data[data != 0])` and `var(data[data != 0])`. Your data is unlikely to be from a zero-inflated Poisson distribution. 3) I don't think you can use `fitdist` with this distribution. First, `fitdist` makes the same mistake as you in assuming `sigma` is the standard deviation. That can be fixed. But then, when I use simulated data, I get errors because the `d/pZIP` functions don't behave like expected for incorrect input.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `VGAM::*zipois()` instead of `gamlss.dist::*ZIP()`. The starting parameters are a bit different, see `?dzipois`, and don't necessarily have to be the mean of your input.

```
library('fitdistrplus')
library('VGAM')  
fitdist(x, 'zipois', start=list(lambda=1, pstr0=.1))
# $start.arg
# $start.arg$lambda
# [1] 1
# 
# $start.arg$pstr0
# [1] 0.1
# 
# 
# $fix.arg
# NULL
# 
# Fitting of the distribution ' zipois ' by maximum likelihood 
# Parameters:
#   estimate Std. Error
# lambda 12.2009631 0.23823650
# pstr0   0.1187056 0.02069464
# Warning messages:
#   1: In fitdist(x, "zipois", start = list(lambda = 1, pstr0 = 0.1)) :
#   The dzipois function should return a zero-length vector when input has length zero
# 2: In fitdist(x, "zipois", start = list(lambda = 1, pstr0 = 0.1)) :
#   The pzipois function should return a zero-length vector when input has length zero
```

I'm not sure about the warning, though.

You may compare this by using a different vector `x1` (below) which won't fail with `gamlss.dist`.

---

*Data:*

```
x <- c(0, 1, 0, 11, 2, 0, 3, 0, 0, 2, 1, 3, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 3, 
0, 0, 0, 8, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 2, 7, 0, 0, 0, 5, 2, 3, 6, 1, 1, 
5, 2, 9, 0, 0, 1, 21, 16, 2, 9, 6, 25, 2, 1, 12, 16, 14, 15, 
15, 6, 1, 12, 12, 13, 5, 5, 6, 4, 7, 11, 8, 4, 5, 8, 3, 8, 4, 
7, 4, 7, 2, 5, 6, 4, 5, 1, 0, 8, 5, 6, 8, 9, 8, 9, 7, 7, 9, 8, 
9, 4, 4, 7, 13, 9, 13, 12, 10, 9, 8, 7, 11, 5, 5, 0, 1, 33, 4, 
22, 19, 22, 9, 5, 4, 17, 7, 7, 4, 5, 3, 0, 0, 9, 3, 0, 0, 36, 
40, 5, 4, 0, 11, 0, 7, 5, 25, 39, 26, 4, 20, 12, 4, 17, 3, 22, 
12, 14, 8, 9, 11, 7, 11, 10, 9, 16, 6, 24, 8, 5, 6, 14, 3, 9, 
4, 1, 20, 0, 1, 7, 9, 0, 12, 2, 29, 56, 16, 8, 28, 0, 19, 25, 
35, 87, 56, 66, 60, 58, 14, 10, 12, 13, 13, 34, 26, 18, 13, 22, 
13, 12, 15, 41, 11, 11, 11, 5, 6, 7, 8, 8, 17, 16, 12, 21, 38, 
34, 10, 77, 41, 7, 12, 1, 16, 20, 8, 5, 2, 20, 7, 16, 12, 6, 
10, 31, 12)

x1 <- c(0, 63, 1, 4, 1, 44, 2, 2, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 3, 
0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
6, 1, 11, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2)
```

Comment: Are you sure that this actually fits a zero-inflated distribution? I get exactly the same lambda and uncertainty with `print(fitdist(data, 'pois', start = list(lambda = 10), discrete = TRUE, method = "mle"))`. But of course, OP's data might not be zero-inflated.

Comment: @Roland You're right, thanks, `pstr0=`  also needs to be optimized, currently it fits just a Poisson, I'll edit that.

Comment: Appears to work but is just a very bad fit with OP's data. Maybe add some plots? `hist(data, freq = FALSE, breaks = 0:90 - 0.5); curve(dzipois(x, lambda = 12.2, pstr0 = 0.12), add = TRUE, col = "blue", from = 0, to = 90, type = "p", n = 91)`

Comment: @Roland Sure, fit was not asked, though:) Also see plots in [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67748368/6574038).